# The PowerQuery Editor throw me an Error on my tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Yesterday i was editing a couple of tables and these perfectly worked. 
Today i turned on my pc and when **i accessed to the PowerQuery Editor it returns me an Error message** but it just appears in the PowerQuery Editor.

The thing is that i can still work with these tables on my dashboard but i can't edit them in the PowerQuery Editor

I can't understand why this doesn't work. It took me a long time to edit the tables and when it show me message to go to the Error i modify or delete the part that returns me the error i close the application and get into again and the same happens.

[Here i show the table out the PowerQuery Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Jzi.png)

[Here i show the Error that returns me when i get into the Power Query Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tM5Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error seems pretty self explanatory - column `'    Todas las APTs'` isn't found in your source data.

I'd suggest checking the source file, to see if your data content has changed, then change your query accordingly. It may be worth trimming your data before promoting headers, to eliminate those multiple spaces before the actual column header.